# how to calculate the precision and F1?

Tags: machine-learning, precision, naivebayes

> i am using TF_IDF for for feature selection and Naive Bayes Classifier. i want to calculate the total
> accuracy and precision.

```
accuracy = train_model(naive_bayes.MultinomialNB(), xtrain_count, train_y, xvalid_count)
  print("NB, Count Vectors: ", accuracy)

 # Naive Bayes on Word Level TF IDF Vectors
  accuracy = train_model(naive_bayes.MultinomialNB(), xtrain_tfidf, train_y, xvalid_tfidf)
    print("NB, WordLevel TF-IDF: ", accuracy)

    # Naive Bayes on Ngram Level TF IDF Vectors
   accuracy = train_model(naive_bayes.MultinomialNB(), xtrain_tfidf_ngram, train_y, 
   xvalid_tfidf_ngram)
  print("NB, N-Gram Vectors: ", accuracy)

 # Naive Bayes on Character Level TF IDF Vectors
  accuracy = train_model(naive_bayes.MultinomialNB(), xtrain_tfidf_ngram_chars, train_y, 
   xvalid_tfidf_ngram_chars)
  print("NB, CharLevel Vectors: ", accuracy)
```

Comment: Nice talking to you
hope your problem is resolved

Answer (score 3):

use this:

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

print(classification_report(true_value,predicted_value))
```

this will give you all that you want

Comment: what is true value and predicted value?

Comment: what do you want to calculate accuracy and f1 for

Comment: what are you using natural language processing for??

Comment: i  am receiving the three different accuracies, word, character and N gram level, idk which one to use , i wanted one accuracy as a result.

Comment: please give a brief about your project @ MR.Robot

Comment: i want to calculate the accuracy  by using TF_IDF as feature selection and Naive Baise as classifier, but as TF-IDF gives 3 kind of features. as you can see above, the model is being used at different categories. i want one accuracy as whole my model perdicted.

Comment: According to me if you are on a spam vs ham type of project then you should consider words or N-grams

Comment: if you are on vowel detection or some kind of that thing then you should go with the character one

Comment: In max of the cases the words accuracy is the best

Comment: Are you using tfidftransformer or anything else of tfidf

Comment: And tfidf dont give you the accuracy , it gives you the frequency, both are different

Comment: i have a title(where paper published)of research paper and abstract of research paper. so i have to perdict  the where paper should publish.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218091/discussion-between-divyessh-maheshwari-and-mr-robot).